# Como criar uma condição "se todos os elementos de uma lista então dentro de uma lista de sets" (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, set

Estou tentando dizer: "Se todos elementos da uma lista estão em uma lista de conjuntos".

```
a= [0,1,2,3,4]
b=[ 3,4,5,6,7]
c=[0,1,8,9,10]
d=[0,1]

e= set(a).intersection(b)
f = set(a).intersection(c)

g = [e,f]
print (g)

if all(d) in g : # aqui está meu problema 
    print ('done')
```

Já que a lista `d` é igual a `[0,1]` e a lista de conjuntos (sets) `g` é igual a `[{3, 4}, {0, 1}]`, por que `'done'` não é impresso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua pergunta foi: Como a lista d é igual a [0,1] e a lista de conjuntos (sets) "g" é igual a [{3, 4}, {0, 1}], porque 'done' não é impresso?

A resposta para a pergunta é: "Como d é uma lista e g é uma lista de sets, o Python compara se eles são o mesmo tipo de objeto antes de comparar os elementos. Também é importante notar que igualdade entre listas (list_a == list_b) só é verdadeira se ambas possuírem os mesmos elementos e na mesma ordem."

'''python

```
a= [0,1,2,3,4] # Isso é uma lista, lista são conjuntos ordenados de dados
b=[ 3,4,5,6,7] # isso também é uma lista
c=[0,1,8,9,10] # também
d=[0,1]        # idem

e= set(a).intersection(b) # Aqui você criou um set a partir da lista a e tirou a interceção com b, o resultado é um set
f = set(a).intersection(c) # Sets são conjuntos não ordenados de dados

g = [e,f] # aqui você criou G como uma lista de sets [{3,4},{0,1}]
print (g)


#if all(d) in g:      
#    print ('done')
print(all(d)) # resulta em False
print(False in g,all(d) in g) #resulta em False tambem.
print(d in g) # Também é False, d é uma lista com 2 inteiros, g é uma lista com 2 sets
print(set(d) in g) # Aqui você converte d de lista para set antes de fazer a procura, então ele retorna True

if set(d) in g:
    print('done')
```

'''
- Não é muito bom, e em geral não funciona, fazer comparações entre dois tipos diferentes a não ser que exista alguma forma dentro do objeto que o compare...

- Se g fosse um set e não uma lista de sets você poderia usar issubset() ou issuperset() (referência https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)
- Outra alternativa é, você quiser que: lista d = [0,1] seja considerada dentro de algo como h = [{0,1,2},{3,4,5}] pois d está contido no conjunto 1 da lista h

Logo:

```
d_set = set(d) # convertendo o tipo

contido = d_set.issubset(h) # cria uma lista com a resposta se d está contido em algum conjunto de d

if any(contido): # ou, juntando as linhas: if any(set(d).issubset(h)):
   print('done')
```

O canal Ignorância Zero (em português) no youtube explica muito bem isso nas seguintes aulas:
[Aula 32: Comparação entre listas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruHkhrXmTRE&list=PLfCKf0-awunOu2WyLe2pSD2fXUo795xRe&index=33) [Aula 117: Sets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZYKXROfpWo&list=PLfCKf0-awunOu2WyLe2pSD2fXUo795xRe&index=118)

Comment: Como vai, Pedro? Considerando que o site é em português, traduza as partes em inglês da sua resposta. Você pode ainda sugerir uma edição na pergunta traduzindo-a para português. Olhando o perfil do AP fica bem claro que ele é brasileiro e, como normalmente acontece, confundiu o site que fez a pergunta com o SOen. ;D

Comment: Feito, LipESprY eu disse que ia responder em português e me contrariei no final kkkkkkk

Comment: Pode tirar a parte em inglês da sua resposta. A pergunta dele TEM que de ser traduzida. Vai ficar um "furo" na sua resposta. kk

Comment: Pronto, sugeri a edição na pergunta dele mas ela é um pouquinho ambígua. Dei resposta para todas as interpretações que eu pude pensar.

Comment: Agora tá filé! ;)

Comment: Obrigado! :D
Aproveitei pra adicionar algumas referências de estudo de sets e listas.

Comment: Depois dá uma lida em [Formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) que vai alavancar as suas respostas e perguntas. ;)

Comment: Eu conheço Markdown, HTML e LaTex o meu problema real é escrever de forma bonitinha usando o que eu sei de Markdown e HTML kkkkkkkkkk
Mas obrigado pela dica, vou dar umas olhadinhas pq o Markdown varia de plataforma pra plataforma (Git, Jupyter, etc)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou. E vlw pelas referencias tbm !

Comment: De nada @VitorOliveira ! Se puder aceitar a resposta eu agradeço (estou tentando construir uma reputação pra pelo menos poder comentar livrement no stackoverflow :3 )